# Display only certain part of an image and resize it with GD

Tags: php, image, resize, gd

I currently have a script ready that resizes a whole image with GD but I need to get a specific part of an image to display and resize only that specific part.

This is the image:

> http://craffy.gdscei.com/enjikaka.png

This is what needs to be displayed, took out the rest with Photoshop:

> http://craffy.gdscei.com/enjikakap.png

The final image needs to be 150x150.

This is the script i tried:

```
<?php

    $srcp = imagecreatefrompng("enjikaka.png");
    $destp = imagecreate(150, 150);
    imagecopyresampled($destp, $srcp, 0, 0, -8, -8, 150, 150, 64, 32);
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($destp);

?>
```

But this one does not pick the correct part of the image. Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why the (-8, -8)? Those should be the upper left corner of your area to copy. It should be 8, 8. And the last two parameters: (64, 32) are the width and height of your source area. Those should be 8, 8 too.

```
imagecopyresampled ($destp, $srcp, 0, 0, 8, 8, 150, 150, 8, 8);
```

I assume here that your source image is built up by 8x8 units. You should check the coordinates in photosop.

I suggest you read the [documentation of the function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php). That shopuld be the first thing you do when things do not go as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
$srcp = imagecreatefrompng("enjikaka.png");
$destp = imagecreate(150, 150);
imagecopy($despt, $srcp, $dst_x , $dst_y , $src_x , $src_y , $src_w , $src_h);
```

I think you should include this call to imagecopy in your script, which should handle the cropping of the image.

Comment: Does not work, displays a blank page: http://craffy.gdscei.com/ppic.php , code i used: `$srcp = imagecreatefrompng("enjikaka.png");$destp = imagecreate(150, 150);imagecopy($destp, $srcp, 0, 0, -8 -8, 64, 32);header('Content-type: image/png');imagepng($destp);`

Comment: those -8 coordinates looks suspicious, though not sure whether it is that causes the problem